# creating table from string by splitting php

Tags: php, html

I have an string in php like this `pid1+2+price1+20+qty1+2+pid2+3+price2+20+qty2+1+` which is an outcome processing of some function. now I need to create table which should display the above result as

```
      pid price qty
       2    20   2
       3    40   1
```

note: the result should be displayed as a string thanks

the function which i used to create the string is

```
$a=var_export($_REQUEST);
$b ='';
foreach($_REQUEST as $key=>$value)
{
    $b.=$key."+".$value."+";
}
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Is there any way you could serialize the function output?  That would save a ton of time/processing.

Comment: This is extremely insecure, as anybody can pass whatever parameters they want to your script via `$_REQUEST`.

Comment: ya tried ..... the output itself is the serialize value but i append + sign for processing data(spiliting) ..

Comment: why do you process the string instead of processing the array into HTML directly?

Comment: how could i process the array into html .. any guides thanks

Comment: the var_export makes zero sense

Comment: What are you using `var_export()` for? The rest of the code doesn't depend on it.

Answer (score 0):

```
$array = array();
foreach ($_REQUEST as $key => $value) {
  preg_match('/^([a-z]+)(\d+)$/', $key, $match);
  $array[$match[2]][$match[$1] = $value;
}
echo "<table><tr><th>pid</th><th>price</th><th>qty</th></tr>";
foreach ($array as $row) {
  echo "<tr><td>$row[pid]</td><td>$row[price]</td><td>$row[qty]</td></tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```